# Theme resources for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm now reading about [theme resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_FontSizes) available on Windows Phone and trying to use some in my project. However, it seems, that only part of them are valid, for instance:

```
Error   2   The resource "PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge" could not be resolved.
```

Why is it so? Is there somewhere more recent repository of theme resources?

---

**Edit:** On request - usage

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BaseButton">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
```

Comment: How do you apply that resource, can you give an example?

Comment: Where `PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge` is merged in the Application?

Comment: @Sankarann What do you mean by "merged in the Application"? This is a style for button; the file in which is quoted line is loaded in `Page.Resources` -> `ResourceDictionary.MergedResources`. Does it matter? This static resource doesn't work even if I use it explicitly in Page's XAML, for instance in `TextBox.FontSize`.

Comment: Check `PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge` is merged in the scope of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource you're trying to use is available only in Windows Phone Silverlight (7.1, 8 & 8.1).

You're probably making a WinRT app, in which case that resource is not predefined.

You can find a bunch of resource definitions in Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\Include\abi\Xaml\Design\generic.xaml

Answer (score 1):

Some of the static resources we are used to in 8.0 or Silverlight builds are different in the 8.1 RT only builds. does this apply to you?